# Terminal cannot seem to find file

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to copy an .iso file to a usb on my mac (El Capitain). I'm am doing this via the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo dd if=~/Desktop/WindowsSP1.iso of=/dev/rdisk2s1 bs=1m
```

For some reason I get : `No such file or directory`
which I don't understand as the file is there. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: does a command like `echo if=~/Desktop/WindowsSP1.iso` show your home directory expanded out?

Comment: The echo command shows this: if=~/Desktop/WindowsSP1.iso

Comment: hmm, can you edit the question with what `ls ~/Desktop/*.iso` shows?

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end I used Unebootin to create copy the .iso file.

Comment: That's wrong. I in fact did it with Boot Camp on Mac OSX, NOT Unetbooti.